# Global menu bar not showing any menus (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: panel, appmenu

Global menu bar in Ubuntu 14.04 is not showing any menus.

Local menus don't show whether I select "show the menus for a window in the window's title bar" or "in the menu bar".

Here are the screenshots:

Pointer over window:

[image]

Pointer over menu bar:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the Firefox you are using from the official ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @xangua Yes. I got the Firefox menu to show by enabling it in through Firefox's customize option, but it's showing inside Firefox window, not on the global menu bar, even though it should be appearing there according to settings in Appearence > Behavior. This is happening with all programs I've tried.

Comment: Sounds like you uninstalled the appmenu packages responsible for the globalmenu.

Comment: @xangua It's a fresh install. I didn't uninstall anything. Do you know the exact package name, cause apt-get can't find appmenu?

Comment: @xangua `indicator-appmenu` and its dependencies weren't installed at all. Installing them solved the problem!